# Why is my convolutional model for detecting image rotation predicting the same class for every picture?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want my model to detect the angle (in 360 classes) using self-generated pictures of text.
To get more information to train on, the training set pictures are newly generated every epoch with a new random rotation.
However it seems like the model is not learning, because it predicts the same class for every picture. I have tried changing the batch size, optimizer, learning rate, more complex models and nothing has helped to solve the problem.

In this example I am using
500 training samples, 50 validation samples and 10 test samples. I have tried for up to 2000 training samples, however the same problem arises.

This is my output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:4070: The name tf.nn.max_pool is deprecated. Please use tf.nn.max_pool2d instead.

Model: "model_1"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 224, 224, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 222, 222, 32)      896       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 111, 111, 32)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 109, 109, 64)      18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 54, 54, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 52, 52, 128)       73856     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 26, 26, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 128)       147584    
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 12, 12, 128)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 18432)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 512)               9437696   
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 360)               184680    
=================================================================
Total params: 9,863,208
Trainable params: 9,863,208
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
2019-11-06 11:08:47.885295: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2019-11-06 11:08:47.901431: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 3408000000 Hz
2019-11-06 11:08:47.902091: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55f4487aac50 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-11-06 11:08:47.902139: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
2019-11-06 11:08:47.903354: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1
2019-11-06 11:08:47.921001: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-06 11:08:47.921953: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 970 major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.1775
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.922112: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.922988: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.923739: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcufft.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.923921: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcurand.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.924921: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusolver.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.925684: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcusparse.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.928111: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
2019-11-06 11:08:47.928199: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-06 11:08:47.929103: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-06 11:08:47.929818: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1763] Adding visible gpu devices: 0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.929844: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:47.976192: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2019-11-06 11:08:47.976213: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
2019-11-06 11:08:47.976219: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N 
2019-11-06 11:08:47.976372: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-06 11:08:47.977217: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-06 11:08:47.978039: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2019-11-06 11:08:47.978851: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1326] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 3466 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 970, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.2)
2019-11-06 11:08:47.980313: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x55f449158000 executing computations on platform CUDA. Devices:
2019-11-06 11:08:47.980326: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor device (0): GeForce GTX 970, Compute Capability 5.2
WARNING:tensorflow:From /home/lisa/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:422: The name tf.global_variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.global_variables instead.

Epoch 1/50
2019-11-06 11:08:48.922378: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.10.0
2019-11-06 11:08:49.080712: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7
16/16 [==============================] - 3s 199ms/step - loss: 10271548.3852 - mse_angle: 88.4758 - val_loss: 6.0310 - val_mse_angle: 83.5972
Epoch 2/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 84ms/step - loss: 6.0294 - mse_angle: 87.3988 - val_loss: 6.2498 - val_mse_angle: 90.8889
Epoch 3/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 6.9000 - mse_angle: 90.9215 - val_loss: 6.2606 - val_mse_angle: 96.1042
Epoch 4/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 6.0261 - mse_angle: 90.2238 - val_loss: 6.1281 - val_mse_angle: 89.1111
Epoch 5/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 6.0339 - mse_angle: 90.6246 - val_loss: 6.1609 - val_mse_angle: 84.5764
Epoch 6/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9953 - mse_angle: 90.6105 - val_loss: 6.0373 - val_mse_angle: 97.3819
Epoch 7/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9419 - mse_angle: 90.0617 - val_loss: 6.0082 - val_mse_angle: 99.2257
Epoch 8/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9563 - mse_angle: 89.2258 - val_loss: 6.0243 - val_mse_angle: 99.2257
Epoch 9/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9515 - mse_angle: 92.9902 - val_loss: 6.0726 - val_mse_angle: 87.7812
Epoch 10/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9554 - mse_angle: 89.0434 - val_loss: 6.0980 - val_mse_angle: 81.9757
Epoch 11/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9761 - mse_angle: 90.9699 - val_loss: 6.1573 - val_mse_angle: 99.1910
Epoch 12/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9674 - mse_angle: 87.5254 - val_loss: 6.1502 - val_mse_angle: 91.5312
Epoch 13/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9457 - mse_angle: 90.9098 - val_loss: 6.1447 - val_mse_angle: 89.7708
Epoch 14/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9803 - mse_angle: 92.3281 - val_loss: 6.1520 - val_mse_angle: 97.5417
Epoch 15/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9663 - mse_angle: 91.3766 - val_loss: 6.1332 - val_mse_angle: 81.1562
Epoch 16/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9707 - mse_angle: 89.2891 - val_loss: 6.0442 - val_mse_angle: 88.7361
Epoch 17/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9691 - mse_angle: 87.9980 - val_loss: 5.8971 - val_mse_angle: 81.1562
Epoch 18/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9675 - mse_angle: 87.8605 - val_loss: 5.9070 - val_mse_angle: 81.1562
Epoch 19/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step - loss: 5.9816 - mse_angle: 88.3820 - val_loss: 6.0384 - val_mse_angle: 90.0694
Epoch 20/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 6.0144 - mse_angle: 91.3855 - val_loss: 6.1066 - val_mse_angle: 90.0694
Epoch 21/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9556 - mse_angle: 92.5727 - val_loss: 6.2307 - val_mse_angle: 86.2465
Epoch 22/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9522 - mse_angle: 90.1418 - val_loss: 6.1750 - val_mse_angle: 81.9062
Epoch 23/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step - loss: 5.9603 - mse_angle: 88.3703 - val_loss: 6.0286 - val_mse_angle: 81.9062
Epoch 24/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9608 - mse_angle: 90.1531 - val_loss: 5.9816 - val_mse_angle: 97.9549
Epoch 25/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9764 - mse_angle: 88.8660 - val_loss: 6.0606 - val_mse_angle: 89.0174
Epoch 26/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9771 - mse_angle: 90.2336 - val_loss: 6.0759 - val_mse_angle: 83.8507
Epoch 27/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 6.0073 - mse_angle: 90.3863 - val_loss: 6.0298 - val_mse_angle: 83.8507
Epoch 28/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9664 - mse_angle: 89.0832 - val_loss: 5.9718 - val_mse_angle: 83.5972
Epoch 29/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9445 - mse_angle: 88.3340 - val_loss: 5.9844 - val_mse_angle: 82.4306
Epoch 30/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step - loss: 5.9596 - mse_angle: 90.2934 - val_loss: 5.8805 - val_mse_angle: 83.0521
Epoch 31/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9729 - mse_angle: 91.9238 - val_loss: 5.9500 - val_mse_angle: 84.4444
Epoch 32/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9743 - mse_angle: 90.0250 - val_loss: 6.0221 - val_mse_angle: 97.5556
Epoch 33/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step - loss: 5.9469 - mse_angle: 86.5922 - val_loss: 6.0201 - val_mse_angle: 87.6076
Epoch 34/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9822 - mse_angle: 93.8836 - val_loss: 5.9119 - val_mse_angle: 81.3472
Epoch 35/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 81ms/step - loss: 5.9751 - mse_angle: 88.9707 - val_loss: 5.9052 - val_mse_angle: 99.3993
Epoch 36/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9564 - mse_angle: 89.6219 - val_loss: 5.9162 - val_mse_angle: 92.5278
Epoch 37/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9864 - mse_angle: 94.1816 - val_loss: 5.9559 - val_mse_angle: 90.5278
Epoch 38/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9566 - mse_angle: 88.3102 - val_loss: 6.0087 - val_mse_angle: 99.3993
Epoch 39/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9639 - mse_angle: 91.0492 - val_loss: 5.9907 - val_mse_angle: 94.2361
Epoch 40/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9792 - mse_angle: 88.0059 - val_loss: 5.8827 - val_mse_angle: 94.3056
Epoch 41/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9297 - mse_angle: 92.0566 - val_loss: 5.8013 - val_mse_angle: 94.6319
Epoch 42/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 84ms/step - loss: 5.9666 - mse_angle: 88.4168 - val_loss: 5.8768 - val_mse_angle: 99.4826
Epoch 43/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9887 - mse_angle: 90.3191 - val_loss: 5.9197 - val_mse_angle: 96.8611
Epoch 44/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9889 - mse_angle: 87.8867 - val_loss: 5.8738 - val_mse_angle: 96.6875
Epoch 45/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 5.9694 - mse_angle: 92.4437 - val_loss: 5.8639 - val_mse_angle: 98.7222
Epoch 46/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9560 - mse_angle: 89.9125 - val_loss: 5.8387 - val_mse_angle: 82.4965
Epoch 47/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9468 - mse_angle: 89.7066 - val_loss: 5.9525 - val_mse_angle: 87.1632
Epoch 48/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 83ms/step - loss: 6.0111 - mse_angle: 89.5977 - val_loss: 5.9091 - val_mse_angle: 96.6875
Epoch 49/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9648 - mse_angle: 89.0430 - val_loss: 5.9656 - val_mse_angle: 92.8368
Epoch 50/50
16/16 [==============================] - 1s 82ms/step - loss: 5.9234 - mse_angle: 91.1891 - val_loss: 5.9717 - val_mse_angle: 99.2257
for image 0 angle: 312, pred: 46
for image 1 angle: 202, pred: 46
for image 2 angle: 235, pred: 46
for image 3 angle: 286, pred: 46
for image 4 angle: 226, pred: 46
for image 5 angle: 76, pred: 46
for image 6 angle: 91, pred: 46
for image 7 angle: 91, pred: 46
for image 8 angle: 97, pred: 46
for image 9 angle: 263, pred: 46
```

This is my model.py:

```
import numpy as np
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Flatten
from keras.models import Model
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing import image as keras_image
from keras.utils import Sequence
from keras.utils.np_utils import to_categorical
from PIL import Image
import math
from random import randint
import os
from numpy import argmax
from create_text_images import create_data

def get_dataset(directory, name):
    """
    Resize the pictures in the directory and return as a numpy array.
    """
    X_train = []
    for i, img_name in enumerate(os.listdir(directory)):
        img_path = os.path.join(directory, img_name)
        with Image.open(img_path) as img:
           img = img.resize((262, 262))
           x = keras_image.img_to_array(img)
        X_train.append(x)
    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    return X_train

def rotate_pictures(X_images):
    """
    Randomly rotate the picture, then crop it to size 224x224.
    Return the image as x normalized /255
    and the rotation (converted to 360 categories) as y.
    """
    X_train, y_train = [], []
    for i, img in enumerate(X_images):
        img = keras_image.array_to_img(img)
        rotation = randint(0, 359)
        img = img.rotate(rotation, resample=Image.BICUBIC)
        w, h = img.size
        img = img.crop(((w//2 - 112),(h//2 - 112), (w//2 + 112), (h//2 + 112)))
        x = keras_image.img_to_array(img)/255.0
        X_train.append(x)
        y_train.append(rotation)
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes=360)
    X_train = np.array(X_train)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    return X_train, y_train

class data_generator(Sequence):
    """
    On initiation, create x and y data with the rotated pictures and their rotation.
    If the dataset is 'train', then rotate original pictures again after every epoch.
    """
    def __init__(self, images, name, batch_size):
        self.images = images
        self.name = name
        self.x, self.y = rotate_pictures(self.images)
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.indices = np.arange(self.x.shape[0])
        self.on_epoch_end()
    def __len__(self):
        return math.ceil(self.x.shape[0] / self.batch_size)
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        inds = self.indices[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_x = self.x[inds]
        batch_y = self.y[inds]
        return batch_x, batch_y
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        if self.name == "train":
            self.x, self.y = rotate_pictures(self.images)

def mse_angle(y_true, y_pred):
    """
    Calculate the mean difference between the true angles
    and the predicted angles. Each angle is represented
    as a binary vector.
    """
    a = K.argmax(y_true)
    b = K.argmax(y_pred)
    diff = 180 - abs(abs(a - b) - 180)
    return K.mean(K.cast(K.abs(diff), K.floatx()))

train_dir = "train/"
val_dir = "val/"
test_dir = "test/"
number_of_epochs = 50
number_of_classes = 360
input_shape = (224, 224, 3)
activation_fn = 'softmax'
batch_size = 32

create_data(train_dir, 500)
X_train = get_dataset(train_dir, "train")
train_generator = data_generator(X_train, "train", batch_size)
create_data(val_dir, 50)
X_val = get_dataset(val_dir, "val")
val_generator = data_generator(X_val, "val", batch_size)
create_data(test_dir, 10)
X_test = get_dataset(test_dir, "test")
X_test, y_test = rotate_pictures(X_test)

input_tensor = Input(shape=input_shape)
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_tensor)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2,2), strides=(2,2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
output_tensor = Dense(number_of_classes, activation=activation_fn)(x)
model = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor)
model.summary()

model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer=Adam(lr=0.1),
        metrics=[mse_angle]
        )

history = model.fit(
        train_generator,
        epochs=number_of_epochs,
        validation_data=val_generator
        )
model.save_weights('model_weights.h5')

predictions = model.predict(X_test)

for i, prediction in enumerate(predictions):
    angle = argmax(y_test[i])
    pred = argmax(prediction)
    print("for image {0} angle: {1}, pred: {2}".format(i,  angle, pred))
```

To run the code it needs to be placed in a directory with three empty folder (val, train, test) and create_test_images.py:

```
import random
import string
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont

def get_random_string(stringLength):
    characters = 10*string.ascii_letters + 100*' ' + string.punctuation*2 + string.digits
    return ''.join(random.choice(characters) for i in range(stringLength))

def get_random_text(lines_min, lines_max, char_min, char_max, newline_min, newline_max):
    lines = ''
    for line in range(random.randint(lines_min, lines_max+1)):
        lines += get_random_string(random.randint( char_min, char_max+1))
        lines += '\n' * random.randint(newline_min, newline_max+1)
    return lines

def create_random_image(directory, file_name, paragraphs_min, paragraphs_max, fontsize_min, fontsize_max,
                      lines_min, lines_max, char_min, char_max, newline_min, newline_max):
    img = Image.new('RGB', (876, 876), color = 'white')
    img.alpha_channel = False
    d = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
    for i in range(random.randint(paragraphs_min, paragraphs_max+1)):
        fnt = ImageFont.truetype('Roboto-Black.ttf', random.randint(fontsize_min, fontsize_max+1))
        d.text((50,100+random.uniform(300, 500)*i),
               get_random_text(lines_min, lines_max, char_min, char_max, newline_min, newline_max),
               fill='black', font=fnt) 
    img.save('{0}/{1}.png'.format(directory, file_name))

def create_data(directory, count):
    for i in range(0, count):
        create_random_image(directory, i, 3, 6, 30, 70, 1, 3, 10, 100, 1, 3)
```

Would really appreciate any tips!

Edit: removed two unused lines of codes

Comment: Have you tried rephrasing your problem to a regression problem, i.e. predicting the angle itself as continuous number, instead of a classification problem? If you have 2000 samples and 360 classes you have on average 5-6 images per class which is not enough. If you are unlucky you don't have any examples for some classes. What happens if you use less classes? E.g. just predicting if the angle is between 0°-90°, 90°-180°, ...

Comment: Wouldn't it be fine to have few samples, since it produces a newly rotated dataset for x every epoch by rotating all sample pictures? Anyway, thanks for the tips, I will try it out and post the results!

Comment: I just tried a regression model, but that predicted 1.0 for every class, and a model with 4 classes, which also predicted the same class for every picture. I feel like there is probably something wrong with my data, but I don't know what. When I show() the images and print the rotation in rotate_pictures, they look fine to me.

Comment: Did you changed the output dimension to only one neuron with ReLU activation instead of softmax and did you use MSE as loss function? Labels must be continuous numbers as well for this case. Btw try to stick to the default values for optimizers, it's not really worth optimizing them until you have a working model imo.

Comment: Yes, for the regression I used ReLU activation, MSE loss, 1 output class and converted the rotation to float() before appending it to the y-array.

Comment: Also, it might be relevant, the validation loss stays exactly the same, and the loss changes slightly (it gets new rotations every epoch), so it seems like the model is not updating the weights at all..

Comment: @Lisa Can you share your code in github with tutorial for custom image. I also trying the same thing.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61555438/predict-image-angel-with-rotnet-and-python?noredirect=1

Comment: The validation loss isn't correct, for predicting angles you do not want to use MSE but CrossEntropy, MSE will be large for a prediction of 10 when the real value is 350, but the real difference here is 20, not 340.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As indicated in my comments, using your provided code I could reproduce your problem and rephrased it from a *classification* problem with 260 classes to a *regression* problem.

Thus I changed the number of output neurons to only one with sigmoid activation, changed the labels to continuous numbers and normalized them (division by 360) to have numbers between 0 and 1, changed the loss function to MSE and used default values for the optimizer.

With these modifications I got this result after 10 epochs of training:

```
for image 0 angle: 0.7416666666666667, pred: [0.7266706]
for image 1 angle: 0.8111111111111111, pred: [0.8449749]
for image 2 angle: 0.7777777777777778, pred: [0.84269005]
for image 3 angle: 0.12222222222222222, pred: [0.14173588]
for image 4 angle: 0.7388888888888889, pred: [0.730219]
for image 5 angle: 0.9694444444444444, pred: [0.9117564]
for image 6 angle: 0.075, pred: [0.07597628]
for image 7 angle: 0.29444444444444445, pred: [0.1829494]
for image 8 angle: 0.10277777777777777, pred: [0.12209181]
for image 9 angle: 0.21388888888888888, pred: [0.31544465]
```

Comment: Your suggestion of regression did work for me in the end, I just didn't use the right learning rate (it's now working with 0.00001), and forgot to remove the argmax() for the prediction at the end. Thank you! I cant upvote because i dont have enough points