# Predict Image angel with Rotnet and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

Hi i am working on classification model to predict angle of image in python for that i am using [Correcting Image Orientation Using Convolutional Neural Networks](https://d4nst.github.io/2017/01/12/image-orientation/) tutorial with ROTNET.

Tutorial is very much explained but training is stuck after 5 to 7 step with `angel error 101` but tutorial says 
we only need to wait for 10 epochs to get an average `angle error of 1-2 degrees!` but i am not reaching there any one having any idea what is thing i am doing wrong.

[image]

Or this is happening because i am using only 50 image to train.
below is type of image which i am using.
[image]

Basically i want to achieve like below shown example 
[image]

Comment: you're using a different dataset, nothing is guaranteed.

Comment: you mean i have to create my own datasets??